# How can I perform mathematical operations on an array of arrays?

Tags: perl, arrays

I have an array of array like below with all numeric values. I want to perform some mathematical operations with these values.

1. Add and print the values of each array elements.
   e.g.

   sum $VAR1 = sum1
   sum $VAR2 = sum2
2. Add all the values from each variables.
   e.g.

   sum $VAR1 + $VAR2 +...+ $VARn = totalsum
3. Finding percentage of each variable's total (`sum1`, `sum2`, etc.) with the totalsum.

   $VAR1 = [
   '17071',
   '16120',
   '16292',
   'upto n numbers'
   ];
   $VAR2 = [
   '1306',
   '1399',
   '1420',
   'upto n numbers'
   ];
   .
   .
   .
   $VARn = [
   '1835',
   '1946',
   'upto n numbers'
   ];

I have tried the below code to perform addition of the first array reference, but it’s not giving me the correct values.

```
my $total = 0;
($total+=$_) for $input[0];
print $total;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
use List::Util qw(sum)
my @sums = map { sum(@{$_}) } @array;
my $sum_of_sums = sum(@sums);
my @percentages = map { $_ / $sum_of_sums } @sums;
```

(In your code, you needed to dereference the arrayref at $input[0].)

Answer (score 3):

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367324/how-can-i-perform-mathematical-operations-on-an-array-of-arrays/1367348#1367348) already covers the simple cases. If you want to do large-scale processing with matrixy data, consider using the [PDL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDL) module.  (Specifically, start with [PDFL::Intro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDL::Intro). Thanks for that, Brad.)

Comment: Who is Brad? What does it refer to?